# Adsense no muestra anuncios

Tags: web, seo, google-adsense

Estoy utilizando anuncios de Adsense en mi Web y, en ocasiones, no se muestran. La cosa es que se genera el hueco para el anuncio, pero no aparece nada en él (de hecho, con el navegador puedo ver el código fuente de Google que está incrustado en el HTML correctamente).

Hay veces que el fallo se produce con un tipo de página en concreto y otras veces que no funciona en ninguna.

¿Es esto normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No no es normal pero hay algunos factores que debes tomar en cuenta

1.La url de registro no tiene codigo de anuncio de AdSense
2.La url de registro no tiene suficientes visitas
3.La url de registro no contiene suficientes articulos
4.La url de registro contiene articulos de ejemplo(Lorem Ipsum)
5.La url de registro contiene articulos que no cumplen con las politicas de AdSense

Si infringes algo de eso es posible que afecte tus anuncios